# How to set the number format of pivot data fields using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I am currently setting the number format using the below code

```
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(0).setNumFmtId(2)
```

But i want to set the number format which is not there in format codes of setNumFmtId function  Ex: 0.0 which is not there in formats

I can only see 0.00 but not 0.0 format in format codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NumFmtId` is either one of the [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) `Id`s. The `Id` `2` is `0.00` and, as you see, there is no `0.0` built in format.

Or it is the `Id` of a custom data format. A such must be created using [Workbook.createDataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createDataFormat--). The `Id` can be got using [DataFormat.getFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html#getFormat-java.lang.String-).

Example:

```
...
DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();
short numFmtId = dataformat.getFormat("0.0");

pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields().getDataFieldArray(0).setNumFmtId(numFmtId);
...
```